# how do I make a generic method lock its type in java?

Tags: java, generics, types, arguments, locked

what I mean about that is that in C# for example I can write a generic method like this:

```
public static void Concatenate<T> (T arg1, T arg2) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(arg1.ToString() + arg2.ToString());
}
```

and then if I call the method in these different ways:

```
Concatenate("one", "two"); // will work just fine, outputs "onetwo"
Concatenate(1, 2); // will also work great, outputs 12
Concatenate("one", 2) // will give a compiler error
```

alternately I could call the method like this: `Concatenate<string>("one", "two");` and be extra sure only strings get in...

now if I try the exact same thing in Java

```
public static <T> void concatenate(T arg1, T arg2) {
    System.out.println(arg1.toString() + arg2.toString());
}
```

and call the method in the exact same way as in the c# example:

```
concatenate("one", "two"); // will work just fine, outputs "onetwo"
concatenate(1, 2); // will also work great, outputs 12
concatenate("one", 2) // will work fine and outputs "one2"
```

as far as I know I can't call the method like `concatenate<String>("One", "Two");` as that will give me an error

is there any way I can add that sort of type safety I found in c#?

so I don't risk being able to just put any type in on either spot and only get a warning...

a better example would be using variable arguments

in C# I'd do:

```
public static void QuickSort<T>(params T[] args) // same as (T... args) in java
{
    // code
}
```

and upon calling it I'd be sure only one kind of parameter got in by for example doing something like:

```
QuickSort<int>(5, 9, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1);
```

whereas in java I'd be able to do this:

```
quickSort(5, "nine", 7, 3, "two", 5, 4, 1);
```

and get nothing but a warning from the IDE, whereas it'd give an error in c#

so my question is, is there any way I can "lock" the parameter type in java like I can in c#, a-la `QuickSort<int>(args)` rather than `quickSort(args)`?

Comment: So, you want a generic method that locks it's type to one Object type. Why not just declare the type in the formal parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as far as I know I can't call the method like `concatenate<String>("One", "Two")` as that will give me an error

Actually, you can, only the syntax is a bit different:

```
public class Main {

    public static <T> void concatenate(T arg1, T arg2) {
        System.out.println(arg1.toString() + arg2.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.<String>concatenate("one", "two"); // will work just fine, outputs "onetwo"
        Main.<Integer>concatenate(1, 2); // will also work great, outputs 12
        Main.<String>concatenate("one", 2); // will fail at compile time
    }
}
```

If `concatenate()` were a non-`static` method, the syntax would be `obj.<String>concatenate(...)`.

As to your second example:

```
public class Main {

    public static <T> void quickSort(T... args) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        quickSort(5, "nine", 7, 3, "two", 5, 4, 1);                // warning
        Main.<Integer>quickSort(5, "nine", 7, 3, "two", 5, 4, 1);  // error
    }
}
```

Here, `Main.<Integer>quickSort(...)` fails with the following error:

> The parameterized method quickSort(Integer...) of type Main is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, String, Integer, Integer, String, Integer, Integer, Integer)

Comment: This answer is correct, however... when the method is called without specifying a type, the type of `Object` is assumed - that's why you're not getting a compile error

Comment: but what I meant when I said it couldn't be called in that way, was syntactically, I kinda figured that there possibly was a way to do it... I just didn't know the correct syntax... so in a sense I was right, it isn't possible to do it with c# style syntax...

Answer (score 2):

You can be explicit with the generic parameter, but the syntax is different than the one you tried:

For Instance methods:

```
instance.<String>concatenate("a","b")
```

For static methods:

```
MyClass.<String>concatenate("a","b")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "type safety" in what you are asking. `Concatenate("one", 2)` is pefectly type-safe. There is no reason to disallow it from a type safety point of view. Generics is not for making arbitrary restrictions.